# Not able to parse data in codable. I am able to fetch data but some how once I use decode function I get error

Tags: swift, codable

I am not able to parse the data using decodable. I am able to fetch the data but not able to parse it using decodable function. It says

> unresolved identifier 'data' in that function.

I Have tried various ways but still not getting it.

```
import UIKit    
import PlaygroundSupport    

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

var str = "Hello, playground"

struct category : Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let list: [List]
    let slide: [String]
}

// MARK: - List
struct List: Codable {
    let id, categoryName: String
    let subcategory: [Subcategory]
}

// MARK: - Subcategory
struct Subcategory: Codable {
    let subCategoryID: SubCategoryID
    let subCategoryName, categoryID: String
    let banner: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case subCategoryID = "sub_category_id"
        case subCategoryName = "sub_category_name"
        case categoryID = "category_id"
        case banner
    }
}

enum SubCategoryID: Codable {
case integer(Int)
case string(String)

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    if let x = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
        self = .integer(x)
        return
    }
    if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
        self = .string(x)
        return
    }
    throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(SubCategoryID.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for SubCategoryID"))
}

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
    switch self {
    case .integer(let x):
        try container.encode(x)
    case .string(let x):
        try container.encode(x)
    }

    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    var datatask : URLSessionDataTask?
    let url = "http://comus.in/co/webservice/getCategoryList.php"
    var items = [URLQueryItem]()
    var myURL = URLComponents(string: url)
    let param = ["vendorId":"32"]
    for (key,value) in param {
        items.append(URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value))
    }
    myURL?.queryItems = items
    let request =  URLRequest(url: (myURL?.url)!)

    datatask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
        if error == nil {
            let receivedData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String: Any]
            print(receivedData!)
            let listings = try? JSONDecoder().decode(List.self , from: data)
            if let listings = listings{

            }
        }

    })
    datatask?.resume()
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the schema of the data you're trying to parse please?

Comment: Don't use `try?`, specially not when your code doesn't behave the way you want, Change to `try` and catch and print any error, `do { let listings = try JSONDecoder().decode(List.self , from: data) } catch { print(error) }`. And please clean up the posted code a little by removing all the multiple empty lines

Comment: I have shared the schema of the data in the form of struct which I want to parse and create model. Do you mean something else ?

Comment: No one can help if you don't post the complete error and show the actual JSON you are trying to decode. Change your code as @JoakimDanielson stated and update your question with the complete error and the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple syntax error. Because you missed an `!` after `data` in `decode` function. Also as @Joakim Danielson suggested in comments, don't `try?` when you don't know what is happening. So change this:

```
let listings = try? JSONDecoder().decode(List.self , from: data)
if let listings = listings{

}
```

to this:

```
do {
    let listings = try JSONDecoder().decode(List.self , from: data!)
    print(listings)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```